# Flex force socket to flush

Tags: flash, apache-flex, sockets, actionscript

How can I force the socket to be flushed before next data to be send?

Example code:

```
public function socketSend(data:String):void
{
    socket.writeUTFBytes(data);
    socket.flush();
}
```

This works basically fine. But sometimes, it doesn't flush the socket, but combine current information with next information and send together. This is what I don't want because it breaks my application communication.

For example, if I call `socketSend('command1')` and then call `socketSend('command2')` I am hoping it will send the `command1` first then later `command2`. But sometimes it sends both together, making the send string become `command1command2`. This breaks the application communication.

How can I force it to flush before putting in next set of information? How can I check whether the information is flushed from the socket?

Thank you.

Comment: XY problem.  TCP 101: TCP is an octet, (byte), streaming service.  You cannot transfer messages longer than one byte.  Your application communication is borkened because you have no protocol on top of TCP to parse out your messages from the byte-stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your respond. Can you suggest how to solve the problem? Maybe with example?

Comment: Try terminating your 'command' Strings with a null byte: `'command1\0'` or `'command2' + String.fromCharCode(0)`. Also, you can use the `bytesPending` property of the `Socket` to see if there are any remaining bytes to be flushed. Also, Socket dispatches "outputProgress" when it moves the pending data to the network layer.