# Flash AS3 about flush() command

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sockets

Here is my code

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i ++ ){
        socket.writeUTFBytes("Command"+i);
        socket.flush();
    }
```

The Question is why I add `socket.flush()`, others still received `Command0Command1` instead of `Command0` and `Command1`. I guest there must have some delay between first flush and second flush, so now the only thing I can do is make a timer to solve this problem. Is there other solution?

Comment: And I have seem this page [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772644/flex-force-socket-to-flush

Comment: This one maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552277/when-to-use-writeutf-and-writeutfbytes-in-bytearray-of-as3

Comment: Thanks for helping. It seems must have length of data in data stream to make sure if get the right data.